# Use asterisk sign in env variables value

Tags: linux, bash

I need to define an environment variable with a value of a cron job.
The value would be as the following:

```
"0 0 * * * *"
```

It will be executed as a bash command on linux.
Is It possible?
How could I achive it?

Comment: Should the value include quotes or not? What language are you writing in (bash, POSIX shell, csh, python, perl?)

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! I think grawity said it all: as is, your question does not provide enough information to be answered. Please [**edit your question**](https://superuser.com/posts/1340900/edit) to add more information about what you are trying to do and what you have tried. You can refer to the [help center](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) for guidelines about what to include in your question. Thank you.

Comment: @grawity would be linux bash

Comment: @Nathan.EilishaShiraini done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You don't need to do anything special, except follow the programming language's regular syntax.

For example, in Bash you would use:

```
export myvar="0 0 * * *"
```

In Python:

```
os.environ["myvar"] = "0 0 * * *"
```

Or if the value should indeed include quotes as in your example:

```
export myvar="\"0 0 * * *\""

os.environ["myvar"] = "\"0 0 * * *\""
```

---

You're probably seeing problems with doing this in sh/bash, because `echo $myvar` appears to output the wrong value. But the value stored in the variable is probably perfectly fine – the problem is with how you're trying to *output* the value.

In sh/bash, variable expansion is done as a separate step *before* wildcard expansion. If the variable name is left unquoted, the original command `echo $myvar` will first expand to the correct value `echo 0 0 0 * *` – and *then* the word-splitting and glob-expansion steps are done, turning your output into a list of file names.

(Yes, this could also happen at assignment time. However I've seen it much more commonly that people forget this at output time; assigning a value with spaces probably naturally reminds people of quoting.)

A correct way to output the variable would be `echo "$myvar"`. (To *inspect* a variable's type and raw contents, bash has `declare -p myvar`.)